# How to determine encoding of binary log files

Tags: matlab, binary

I've been given a Matlab toolbox that contains a 'file validation' function to ensure data files are formatted properly before they are passed on to a client. While the function will tell me what lines have formatting problems, there isn't any detail as to what was wrong or what it should be.
I tried digging into the toolbox to try and reverse engineer the required format from the source code but its all in protected .p files. It looks like there are reference files that are in .mtb format (binary log file) but I can't seem to find an encoding that produces anything human readable.
Anyone know how to determine what encoding was used on a binary log file? Unfortunately, our contract prevents me from loading one of the files here.